# Is it possible to burn a filename watermark in the corner of a concatenated image slideshow and have it change for each image?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, concatenation

**What I want to do**: I have a folder with a great bunch of images. Using these files I want to create a slideshow video, while I want the filename of each of the original images burned into the bottom right corner.

**What my current state is**: I made a script to fetch all `.jpg` files in the folder and make a `ffmpeg-readable` list and I know how to concat the images to a slideshow and everything works as intended. I also figured out how to use FFmpeg's drawtext to get a handsome filename stamp.

**Now the problem**: Currently FFmpeg grabs the last filename from the file list (for example IMG_9935.jpg) and burns it into the entire video. But what I want to happen is, that it changes with each 'new' image - just like a timecode would change during the course of the video.

#### Is any of this possible?

**As a side note**: "Why don't you burn the filename beforehand?" I'd like to keep it as flexible as possible. So if there's another way round, I'd like to go that way.

```
for i in *.jpg; do echo "file '$i'" >> files.txt; done

ffmpeg -r 1/3 -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -vf
"eq=text=$(echo $i | rev | cut -d / -f 1 | rev): fontcolor=0x808080:
fontsize=14: x=w-tw- 10:y=h-th-10" -c libx264 filename.mp4
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The concat demuxer allows setting per-file metadata entry, but this has to be done manually.

You would change your script to

```
for i in *.jpg; do echo "file '$i'" >> files.txt; echo "file_packet_metadata url=$i" >> files.txt; done

ffmpeg -r 1/3 -f concat -safe 0 -i files.txt -vf
"drawtext=text='%{metadata\:url}': fontcolor=0x808080:
fontsize=14: x=w-tw- 10:y=h-th-10" -r 12 -c:v libx264 filename.mp4
```